# Destroying Object by multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, free

I'll try to be quick. I have this code here

```cpp
class A {};

A* a = new A;

int main()
{
   delete a;
   delete a;
   return 0;
}
```

This code when executed detects a double free of the pointer a, and the output I get in the console is:

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Which is resonable, but then I did the same experiment with multiple threads:

```cpp
class A {};

A* a = new A;


void func()
{
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
   delete a;
}

int main()
{
   std::thread t{ func };

   delete a;

   t.join();

   return 0;
}
```

And well guess what? The latter code does not a detect double free deletion of pointer a. What is happening?

Comment: What tool did you use so that it generated the quoted message saying that there is a double `free()`? C++, by default, does not do anything like that.

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour. Anything is allowed to happen.

Comment: And this actually means that the destructor can be invoked multiple times by multiple threads, but they will alter regions of memory that can be already occupied by other objects, I don't see the point even if it's kind of allowed.

Comment: @Fureeish If you mean which compiler I'm using, I'm using g++ in a linux environment.

Comment: @limserhane yes, but I saw it running twice by the two threads, first by the main thread, and second time by the thread spawned from the main thread. The destructor runs just fine twice, even after the memory has been deallocated.

Comment: @limserhane so if what you're saying is true, then why I saw a library using locks in a destructor? To protect it from multiple threads to destroy the same object? This means that destructor can actually be called multiple times by multiple threads.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this question. "I did something bad and I was not called out on it"? Yes, nothing stops an object's destructor from running multiple times, although it is in your best interest to prevent this from happening.

Comment: No, it's not allowed under any conditions to destroy an object twice. Using locks in destructor is probably because another thread might still be using the object when its owner wants to destroy it.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen oh yeah i missed that case you right. Yet it's weird tho that nothing happens if I invoke the destructor twice in multiple threads. Maybe for every thread there kind of a cache telling how many times the thread has invoked a free on a pointer. I don't know.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is undefined. "Nothing happens" falls in line with "anything can happen". As well as "program executes as expected", "program crashes", "program only works on full moon" and "program makes [demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)".